# Upload Postgres db on an Amazon VM

Tags: database, postgresql, upload, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine

I've been given a database which I can't handle with my pc, because of little available storage and memory.

The person who gave me this db gave me the following details:

> The compressed file is about 15GB, and uncompressed it's around
>   85-90GB. It'll take a similar amount of space once restored, so make
>   sure the machine that you restore it on has at least 220GB free to be
>   safe. Ideally, use a machine with at least 8GB RAM - although even our
>   modest 16GB RAM server can struggle with large queries on the tweet
>   table.
>
> You'll need PostgreSQL 8.4 or later, and you'll need to create a
>   database to restore into with UTF8 encoding (use -E UTF8 when creating
>   it from the command-line). If this is a fresh PostgreSQL install, I
>   highly recommend you tweak the default postgresql.conf settings - use
>   the pgtune utility (search GitHub) to get some sane defaults for your
>   hardware. The defaults are extremely conservative, and you'll see
>   terrible query performance if you don't change them.

When I told him that my pc sort of sucks, he suggested me to use an **Amazon EC2 instance**.

**My two issues are:**

1. How do I upload the db to an Amazon VM?
2. How do I use it after that?

I'm completely ignorant regarding cloud services and databases as you can see. Any relevant tutorial will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You've said that the database is "compressed" but not how, or what it is. You need to know if it's a `.backup` file (as created by `pg_dump -Fc` or by PgAdmin-III), a plain `.sql` dump file, or even a compressed file system level copy. What file extension, if any, does it have?

Comment: @Athanasia: about deploying PostgreSQL on EC2, you may learn of lot in this excellent conference talk by Christophe Pettus: [PostgreSQL on AWS](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2fHRX-u1X4A) (youtube).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're new to cloud hosting, rather than using EC2 directly consider using [EnterpriseDB's cloud options](https://aws.amazon.com/solution-providers/isv/enterprisedb). [Details here](http://www.enterprisedb.com/cloud-database/pricing-amazon).

If you want to use EC2 directly, sign up and create an instance.

Choose your preferred Linux distro image. I'm assuming you'll use Linux on EC2; if you want to use Windows that's because you probably already know how. Let the new VM provision and boot up, then SSH into it as per the documentation available on Amazon for EC2 and for that particular VM image. Perform any recommended setup for that VM image as per its documentation.

Once you've done the recommended setup for that instance, you can install PostgreSQL:

- For Ubuntu, `apt-get install postgresql`
- For Fedora, `yum install postgresql`
- For CentOS, use the [PGDG yum repository](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/RPM_Installation), *not* the outdated version of PostgreSQL provided.

You can now connect to Pg as the default `postgres` superuser:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

and are able to generally use PostgreSQL much the same way you do on any other computer. You'll probably want to make yourself a user ID and a new database to restore into:

```
echo "CREATE USER $USER;" | sudo -u postgres psql
echo "CREATE DATABASE thedatabase WITH OWNER $USER" | sudo -u postgres psql
```

Change "thedatabase" to whatever you want to call your db, of course.

The exact procedure for restoring the dump to your new DB depends on the dump format.

For `pg_dump -Fc` or PgAdmin-III custom-format dumps:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_restore --dbname thedatabase thebackupfile
```

See "man pg_restore" and the [online documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgrestore.html) for details on `pg_restore`.

For plain SQL format dumps you will want to stream the dump through a decompression program then to psql. Since you haven't said anything about the dump file name or format it's hard to know what to do. I'll assume it's gzip'ed (".gz" file extension), in which case you'd do something like:

```
gzip -d thedumpfile.gz | sudo -u postgres psql thedatabase
```

If its file extension is ".bz2" change `gzip` to `bzip2`. If it's a `.zip` you'll want to `unzip` it then run `psql` on it using `sudo -u postgres psql -f thedumpfilename`.

Once restored you can connect to the db with `psql thedatabase`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate you explained each step.